# Bundle name Sankey plot plotly

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I am wondering how to add bundle name in plotly to Sankey plot. By bundle I understand nodes in one column. From plotly tutorial:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3], # indices correspond to labels, eg A1, A2, A2, B1, ...
      target = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
      value = [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2]
  ))])

fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram", font_size=10)
fig.show()
```

[image]

What I want to add is bundle title like:
[image]

I cannot find option for this in documentation nor I can figure out way to hack it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you think this could be a starting point?

```py
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Sankey(
    node = dict(
      pad = 15,
      thickness = 20,
      line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),
      label = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1", "C2"],
      color = "blue"
    ),
    link = dict(
      source = [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 3], # indices correspond to labels, eg A1, A2, A2, B1, ...
      target = [2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5],
      value = [8, 4, 2, 8, 4, 2]
  )))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[0,1,2], y=[None]*3))
fig.update_xaxes(side='top')
fig.update_layout(title_text="Basic Sankey Diagram",
                  title_x=0.5,
                  font_size=10,
                  plot_bgcolor='white',
                  xaxis = dict(showgrid=False,
                               tickmode = 'array',
                               tickvals = [0, 1, 2],
                               ticktext = ["bundle name 1", "bundle name 2", "bundle name 3"]),
                  yaxis = dict(showgrid=False,
                               showticklabels=False)                             

                                    )

fig.show()
```

[image]

The tricks I used are:

- Add a fake scatter (`y` are `None`)
- Move `xaxes` to the top
- Change background color to `white`
- Get rid of `showgrid` on the two axis
- Add a custom ticks on `xaxis`
- Remove tickslabels on `yaxis`